# Having trouble solving an inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I'm a trying to prove a recurrence relation (by substitution) for an algorithm class
and I'm shamefully stuck in a rather simple looking inequality.

I need to solve this inequality for constant $c$:

$$\frac{3cn}{2} + \frac{n}{\log_{2}n} \ge cn$$

The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the logarithm!

Can anyone could point me in the right direction? Also, are there any good
books or tutorials on this simple subject? I just returned to school and I
can't remember simple things like this...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below the line shows the inequality is true, which I assumed is what you wanted as most algorithm problems come down to proving things not algebra. Re-reading your question shows you want to solve for $c$. Just ignore the $\log_2 n$ as anything special and just do the algebra to get $c$ by itself.

$\frac{3cn}{2}+\frac{n}{\log_2 n} \geq cn \iff 
\frac{n}{\log_2 n} \geq -\frac{1}{2}cn \iff
\frac{-2}{\log_2 n} \leq c$

---

For $n>1$, $\log_2 n > 0$. So $\frac{n}{\log_2 n} > 0$. Hence $\frac{3cn}{2}+\frac{n}{\log_2 n} \geq cn$ since $\frac{3}{2}cn \geq 1cn$.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS  is not defined for $n \in (-\infty,0] \cup \{1\}$.

If $n>1$:
$$c \geq 0 \geq -\log_n (4) = - \frac{\log_2 (4)}{\log_2 (n)} = \frac{-2}{\log_2 (n)}  \iff   \frac{n}{\log_2 (n)} \geq -\frac{nc}{2} \\ \iff \frac{3cn}{2} + \frac{n}{\log_{2}n} \ge cn $$

For $0<n<1$: as $n$ tends to $1$, $c \geq -\log_n (4)$ tends to $\infty$, so one does not want to go there.